# Can't get String Overrides module to work for me

Tags: drupal

I installed the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module and I have two entries in Site Configuration, one for Arabic and the other for English. I had put "Create Advertisement" inside of "Original field (English)" and some Arabic text inside "Replacement field." Nothing happened; no replacement was done.
I know there is something about wrapping the text in the [t()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) function, but I do not know where to do it from. It is easy to do that in the case of replacing a field name but not here in this case. Can I have some help from you? I am using Drupal 6.19.

Answer (score 0):

As reported in the project page, String Overrides can be used to replace anything that is passed through `t()`; if the English string is not used from any modules, you will not see the  Arabic string being used.

If you are using "Create Advertisement" in your module, then the module should contain a call to `t("Create Advertisement")`. `t()` is case sensitive; if you are overriding "Create Advertisement," but the string used is "Create advertisement," then the string it will not be shown in Arabic.
I also think Arabic must be the language set for the page being shown.